# how to sort results in google places api

Tags: google-places-api

I want to sort results fetched via google places api based on increasing distance from "location" (a pair of lat, lng). There is no documentation on their official page. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

It just says:

> Each element of the results array contains a single result from the
>   specified area (location and radius), **ordered by prominence**. The
>   ordering of results can be influenced by check-in activity within your
>   application - Places with many recent check-ins may figure more
>   prominently in your application's results. The result may also contain
>   attribution information which must be displayed to the user.

However they didnt mention anything about their *prominence meter* algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature.

There is a feature request for this in the Places API issue tracker here: 
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3322

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 3):

This has been added to the API, please use the 'rankby=distance' instead of 'radius' in your Place Search Request as described in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests